# Create application by admin for user in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

As an admin I want to create applications in WSO2 API Manager and subscribe these applications on APIs. Then, I wish to associate each application with a certain user in a way that user can invoke APIs from his application, but can not invoke API from other users' applications. I have found one possible solution to share admin's group with users. But it seems not appropriate for me, because if it is the only common group then users will see each others' applications, if it is one group per user the admin's group field will be overflowen in case of great number of users. Please, give me an advise, how to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree that sharing admin groups with users in not always the best way.

One of the measures to control access is using scopes. 
https://wso2.com/library/articles/2017/01/article-an-overview-of-scope-management-with-wso2-api-manager/

You may assign a scope to the API resource calls and restrict the defined scopes to certain user group.

Edit: You can create a role for each API and assign a list of users to the role. This way the users are not restricted to using a specific application, but allowed only APIs which scopes are required and provided

User requesting an access token will have to explicitly request a set of scopes, the API manager will grant only scopes which are allowed by the user roles (groups)

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I just need to clarify my understanding. The process is as follows. Am I right?
1.Admin creates a separate scope for each API.
2.Admin creates applications in WSO2 API Manager and subscribe these applications on APIs. 
3.Admin creates a separate role for each user and assign a list of scopes(APIs) to each role.  
4.User obtains application token to "his" application and is able to invoke only APIs in his scopes.

Comment: nr. 3 - do not overcomplicate it. imho the simplest way is to create a role per API, API scope for such a role and assign a list of users to the role (role per user is usually bad idea)